# Youtube dl mp3 exec

Tags: php, youtube, exec

I have a problem about youtube-dl-mp3 package.This is shell application.I want to use this application with php exec function but it doesn't run.Also doesn't return error code.Help me please.

Youtube-dl-mp3 Repo Link:https://github.com/jweslley/youtube-dl-mp3

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use.

Comment: <?php exec ('youtube-dl-mp3 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G61W0JujLjc');

Comment: Where are the quotes around your URL string? `exec ('youtube-dl-mp3 "youtube.com/watch?v=G61W0JujLjc"');`

Comment: Problem was a quotes.Solved,Thank you.